# Why does the revised version of the “Hello, world!” program from the book Effective C works using `printf`?

Tags: c, printf, puts

I've embarked on learning to program in C. I've started reading Seacord's Effective C book, and I've got confused already on page 6=D
Earlier in the book, there is this little program which he calls the revised version of the "Hello, world!" program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    if (puts("Hello, world!") == EOF) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        // code here never executes
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    // code here never executes
}
```

It works for me as expected. Then Seacord introduces the `printf` function in a section ending with the following paragraph:

> The simplest way to output a string is to use the `puts` function, as previously shown. If you do use `printf` instead of `puts` in the revised version of the “Hello, world!” program, you’ll find it no longer works, because the `printf` function returns status differently than the `puts` function. The `printf` function returns the number of characters printed if it’s successful, or a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred. You can try modifying the “Hello, world!” program to use the `printf` function as an exercise.

This was already confusing just after reading because earlier he writes:

> The `puts` function returns the value of the macro `EOF` (a negative integer) if a write error occurs; otherwise, it returns a nonnegative integer value.

Based on these passages, I can't see a relevant difference between the functions' return statuses. Anyway, I tried this program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    if (printf("%s\n", "Hello, world!") == EOF) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        // code here never executes
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    // code here never executes
}
```

And it worked. I've also tried multiple compilers and versions on https://godbolt.org/, and it worked every time, although I'm fairly inexperienced yet to use this tool, I think.
My question is: what shouldn't work in this example?

On my computer I use

- Windows 10 Home 10.0.19045 build 19045
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.5.1
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 00482-90000-00000-AA637
- Microsoft C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.35.32215 for x64

I used the following command in the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022:
`cl /std:c17 filename.c`

(I apologise for writing so many details, but I don't know yet what's important for you. I welcome any advice on what information to provide in future questions.)

Comment: What is the value of `EOF`?  What if you instead print a string of that length?

Comment: printf returns a count of the number of characters it ouput, thats not equal to EOF, so you dont get the error message. The book means, that if an error occurs you would not see it (printf returns 0, puts return EOF and EOF != 0)

Comment: This is a well-asked question, and that's a good first book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the function `puts` returns `EOF` in case of an error while the function `printf` returns a negative value (not necessary equal to `EOF`) in case of an error.

From the C Standard (7.21.7.9 The puts function)

> 3 **The puts function returns EOF if a write error occurs**; otherwise it
> returns a nonnegative value.

and (7.21.6.3 The printf function)

> 3 The printf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or
> **a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred**.

So this condition for a call of `printf`

```
if (printf("%s\n", "Hello, world!") == EOF)
```

can evaluate to false even if an error occurred.

For `printf` you should write

```
if (printf("%s\n", "Hello, world!") < 0 )
```

Comment: Although this is correct, I'd like to remark that (in most cases anyway) it's pointless to examine the `printf` return value for an error condition because you can't act in a sensible way if an error occurred.

Comment: More information on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535557/why-does-printf-return-a-value).

Answer (score 2):

> what shouldn't work in this example?

`printf()` is documented to return a *negative value* on failure. The *negative number* doesn't have to be the same as `EOF`.

Comparing the return value of `printf()` to `EOF` is wrong in the sense that if `printf()` failed, and it's return value doesn't happen to be the same as `EOF`, the program would continue to execute code instead of exiting, which could lead to some big problems if an application considers a failed `printf()` a fatal error.

The main difference between `puts()` and `printf()` is that on failure, the former returns *`EOF`*, while the latter returns a *negative value*.

And as @Marco commented, it's pointless to check the return value of `printf()` (in most cases), and try to print out a diagnostic message to `stderr` with `fprintf`/`fputs()`, because there is no guarantee that the subsequent calls would succeed and the diagnostic messages would go on forever like so:

```
if (printf ("Hello World.\n") < 0) { 
    if (fprintf (stderr, "printf() failed.\n") < 0) {
        if (fprintf (stderr, "fprintf() failed.\n") {
          /* This goes infinitely. */
```